# Karma, Rails preprocessing coffeescript erb files from gem dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, karma-runner, preprocessor, actioncable

I have a karma test runner that dynamically writes rail's javascript files to a [karma.conf.js](https://gist.github.com/daino3/792c565357e0fca24913c92e45130d4c) file.

Now, everything works (the tests run) if I remove actioncable's javascript files manually from the files list. However, when actioncable's files are added, the preprocessor chokes.

> 24 08 2016 16:56:22.095:ERROR [preprocessor.coffee]: unexpected <
>     at /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/actioncable-6be2604aa719/lib/assets/javascripts/cable.coffee.erb:4
>   24 08 2016 16:56:22.296:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.14 server started at http://localhost:9876/
>   24 08 2016 16:56:22.309:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
>   24 08 2016 16:56:23.106:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket RyL0QOEWkq8inzwAAAAA with id 22283032
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
>     You need to include some adapter that implements **karma**.start method!

Oke doke. So looking at the actioncable erb file:

```
#= require_self
#= require cable/consumer

@Cable =
  INTERNAL: <%= ActionCable::INTERNAL.to_json %>

  createConsumer: (url) ->
    new Cable.Consumer url
```

So the preprocessor is definitely choking on the erb tags in this specific file. I have erb tags in other files, that get processed fine, but those are wrapped in quotes. Is this a preprocessor bug, or is there a quick fix for this that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. My understanding is that you need to compile the erb files down to js files, which will remove the rails syntax. What I did was add to my `development.rb` file:

`config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"`

Which creates the finger printed `application.js` file with all of your compiled scripts, same as production, and places it into `public/dev-assets`

In my karma.conf I have:

```
files: [
  './public/dev-assets/*.js',
   ...
]
```

It's not exactly ideal, since you're working with one big file when writing/debugging tests, but it works with the asset pipeline.

Before I came to that solution, I did add only my specific ng folders to the files array, **skipping the cables file** (you could add it to the excluded files list), which resolved the issue too, but I went with this route because I couldn't get it to play nice with `angular-rails-templates`